# Getting duplicated input events from two separate gamepads on Linux using evdev

Tags: c, linux, input, gamepad

I'm writing an input system for my engine and I'm currently trying to get controller input up and running. I have a third party X-Box controller and PS4 controller for testing. I was successful in getting input from both of them, so I then tested the system with both controllers connected at the same time. That's when I noticed some weird behavior.

If I first read events from the X-Box controller and then the PS4 controller, when I press a button on the X-Box controller, it results in two prints to the console. This is not the case with the PS4 controller.

I reversed the read order and read from the PS4 controller first. Ran the same test and this time I got two prints when pressing a button on the PS4 controller but not on the X-Box one.

After some further debugging I'm ready to believe that my controllers are mirroring each other?

I've tried searching for someone that's experienced this or a similar situation but I've not been successful. Then again I'm not too sure what to search for. From looking at the docs, I didn't see any obvious mention about a case like this, nor did I spot a way of differentiating between controllers to work around the problem.

Below is my code. I open the two files from "/dev/input/by-id"  using open() and store them in state.Gamepads. Every frame I read each and process the event accordingly.

```
struct input_event e;
for (i32 i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    if(state.Gamepads[i] <= 0) { continue; }
    read(state.Gamepads[i], &e, sizeof(e));

    if (e.type == EV_KEY && e.value == 1)
    {
        switch (e.code)
        {
            case BTN_WEST:
            LOG_INFO("BUTTON WEST PRESSED");
            break;
         }
     }

}
```

I expected to get individual and unique input from each gamepad. Instead I get mirrored input.

I'm very new to developing on Linux and it's been a mess to find docs and info about these APIs since I don't know where to look. Has anyone else ran into this? Is this a bug or am I doing this completely wrong?

Comment: Check `read()` return value. What is the point of `if(state.Gamepads[i] <= 0)`? For reading multiple event sources you should use I/O multiplexing (e.g. `poll()` or `epoll_wait()`) or/and non-blocking I/O. Also you can use [libevdev](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/libevdev/doc/latest/) or linux [joystick interface](https://docs.kernel.org/input/joydev/joystick-api.html#initialization) instead of raw `read()`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue thanks to @dimich

The link he provided to the [libevdev](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/libevdev/doc/latest/) docs were extremely helpful with clear examples and descriptions for each function in the API.

I switched from using raw `read()` to `libevdev_next_event()` and that correctly captures individual input from both gamepads.

A full [example](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libevdev/libevdev/blob/master/tools/libevdev-events.c) is also provided in the docs, outlining every step.